# How to check kubeapierrorhigh and how to fix?

Tags: kubernetes

we are receiving alert in opsgenie that KubeApiErrorsHigh, So how to do basic checks and how to fix the issue.

As i'm new in Kubernetes i'm blocked, So please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

This alert will trigger if Kubernetes API Server requests are failing. You should look at the ETCD and Kubernetes API Server logs to check anything wrong going on there.